# Program error for this solution

Tags: python

This is what is available right now

```
l = [list[0]]
list.pop(0)
x = len(list)

for i in range(x+1):
n = len(l)
j = 0

if list[j] > l[n-1]:
    l.append(list[j])
    list.pop(j)
    j = j+1

elif i == len(list):
    l.append(list[j])
    list.pop(j)
print(list)
print(l)
```

`

Some pointers would be really helpful!

Comment: First loop over the sequence and store the increasing values in a new list (removing them from the original sequence).  Then, if any elements are remaining in the original sequence, start from 0 again and append to the new list.  Keep doing this until the original sequence is empty.

Comment: `[1, 2, 11, 19, 2, 5, 9, 8]` is not an increasing sequence, and it isn't a subsequence of the input. Are you supposed to repeatedly find the longest increasing subsequence, remove it, and continue until the input is empty, then concatenate all chosen subsequences together?

Comment: The longest increasing subsequence of that list is `[1, 2, 5, 9, 19]`, or `[1, 2, 5, 8, 19]` not what you say you're looking for as a result. Can you clarify how exactly your desired result relates to the [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `copy` of the list. Iterate through the copy in *successions* and check for monotonically increasing entries to be added to `result` in the current iteration of the `while` loop. Delete the entries as they are added to the `result`.

Repeat the *check-append-delete* cycle in the next iteration of the while loop; until the copy of the list is empty:

```
lst = [1, 2, 2, 2, 11, 5, 9, 8, 19]

lst_cp = lst.copy()
result = []

while lst_cp: # keep iterating until list is empty
    result.append(lst_cp.pop(0))
    for v in lst_cp[:]:
        if v > result[-1]:
            result.append(v)
            lst_cp.remove(v)

print(result)
# [1, 2, 11, 19, 2, 5, 9, 2, 8]
```

Comment: you can also use `lst_cp` as the condition of the while-loop and then do the append first and then for-loop

Comment: @Copperfield Yes, that also does it. Had thought of that but chose to use the  `while True` idiom. Thank you for noting.

Comment: with this change is best to initialize `result` in a empty list because is not guaranty that the first element is lower than the second

Comment: A greedy approach like this isn't guaranteed to get the longest increasing subsequence. For example, if the input is `[1, 5, 2, 3, 4]`, we should probably pick `1 2 3 4` and then `5`, not `1 5` and then `2 3 4`.

Comment: @user2357112 The OP's example describes an outcome that will produce `1 5` then `2 3 4`. The other case you described could be easily gotten by sorting the list

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: The OP's example is disappointingly ambiguous, but it doesn't sound like the subsequences must always continue with the next possible number. It sounds like the subsequences merely have to be increasing, and as long as possible. The problem description sounds like an iterated variation on the [longest increasing subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence), which would choose `1 2 3 4` out of `[1, 5, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: Here's an example that isn't equivalent to sorting: it sounds like `[1, 6, 7, 5, 2, 3, 0, 4]` should be decomposed into `1 2 3 4`, then `6 7`, then either `5` or `0`, then the other.

Comment: @user2357112 Then the OP was differently formulated. One should then expect `[1, 2, 2, 11, 5, 9, 8, 19] -> [1, 2, 5, 8, 2, 11, 19, 9]` instead of `[1, 2, 11, 19, 2, 5, 9, 8]`. You do have a point. Didn't consider those. But this solution should do what they described.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: Hm... actually, now that I look more closely, I would have expected `1 2 5 8 19` or `1 2 5 9 19` as the first subsequence for this input. I guess your code follows the given example, but I suspect that the example might be wrong.